# Pass two values of input fields to script and combine for searching

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my current project, i have two text fields in which user will input requirement and area respectively. Grabbing those values, i have to do an ajax call and fetch the necessary data from the database and return it. The ajax call has to be made as and when the input exceeds 4 characters in any of the text fields. As long as there was only one text field i didn't have any problem.

```
<input type="text" value="requirement" onkeyup="function1(this.value)" />
<input type="text" value="area" onkeyup="function2(this.value)" />

<script>
function function1(valuetosearch)
{
 //make the ajax call
}
</script>

<script>
function function2(valuetosearch2)
{
 //make the ajax call
}
</script>
```

How can i combine the two scripts and pass the data in ajax as an array?
 P.S The main reason for scripting is to do a search combining the two input fields. For example if someone enters house, vehicle in requirement field and place1,place2 in area field. The result search should display the result for the following
1) place1 house
2) place1 vehicle
3) place2 house
4) place2 vehicle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" value="requirement" onkeyup="functionABC()" id="First" />
<input type="text" value="area" onkeyup="functionABC()" id="Second" />

<script>
function functionABC()
{
   var searchString=$("#First").val()+" "+$("#Second").val();
   //make the ajax call
}
</script>
```

Pass "searchString" as a param.

Answer (score 3):

you can set id for each elemnt and get the other's value using

```
document.getElementById("id1").value
```

and then make the ajax request

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/JMpgU/

```
$("input").keyup( function () {
    var str = $(this).val() + " " + $(this).siblings().val();
    alert(str);
   //make the ajax call
});
```

with any number of inputs:
http://jsfiddle.net/JMpgU/2/

```
$("input").keyup( function () {
    var strings = $(this).
                  siblings().
                  addBack().
                  map(function () {
                      return $(this).
                             val();
                  }).
                  toArray();
 //make the ajax call
});
```

Comment: thanks I found the solution to my problem similar to yours.. :)